# Angular - Cannot match routes - Url segment

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I work on a website when people can register, they are either sellers or buyers. They go on "register" then could choose, but then, my site won't find the good route.

**Here is my code:**

```js
import { ComponentsComponent } from './components/components.component';
import { LandingComponent } from './examples/landing/landing.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './examples/login/login.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './examples/profile/profile.component';
import { NucleoiconsComponent } from './components/nucleoicons/nucleoicons.component';
import { SubscriptionArtisanComponent } from './subscription/subscriptionArtisan/subscriptionArtisan.component';
import { SubscriptionComponent } from './subscription/subscription.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'index', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'index', component: ComponentsComponent },
    { path: 'nucleoicons', component: NucleoiconsComponent },
    { path: 'examples/landing', component: LandingComponent },
    { path: 'examples/login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'examples/profile', component: ProfileComponent },
    { path: 'subscribe', component: SubscriptionComponent },
    { path: 'subscribeArtisan', component: SubscriptionArtisanComponent }
];
```

```html
<div ngbDropdownMenu>
             <a class="dropdown-header">Menu</a>
             <a routerLink="subscribe"><button class="btn">S'incrire</button></a>
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
```

```html
<div class="imageettexte2" routerLinkActive="active">
      <a routerLink='subscribeArtisan'><img src="assets/img/SubsArtisan.jpeg" alt="Forest"  class= "rounded img-raised"></a>
      <p>Je suis un artisan</p>
    </div>
```

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'subscribe/subscribeArtisan'
```

Comment: Have you tried `routerLink='/subscribeArtisan'` ?

Comment: I did before sking, but the error was "Error: NG0302: The pipe 'date' could not be found!" :/

Comment: "Error: NG0302: The pipe 'date' could not be found!" has nothing to do with routing.

Comment: From which component this error come from ? Do subscribeArtisan is displayed ?

Comment: No, subscribeArtisan isn't displayed on screen (while I did an HTML for it)

Comment: The second error is due to a module import. Try to comment the HTML with date pipe and test

Comment: holy ****.... thanks a lot.... I used  Bootstrap example (first time on Angular), and I forgot to check the automatic footer u_u

Comment: You should put error message inside quote block not code block.

Answer (score 0):

The `routerLink` is a relative url to the `router-outlet` it's defined in. I assume the `subscribeArtisan` router link is defined inside the `SubscriptionComponent`. There are two ways:

```
<a routerLink="/subscribeArtisan">
```

or

```
<a routerLink="../subscribeArtisan">
```

Comment: I've tried both, but the error is now: "Error: NG0302: The pipe 'date' could not be found!"

Comment: @R3m that just means you didn't import the appropriate module yet :) and is unrelated to your question. But i see from the comments you managed to resolve your issues